# C# - with a reference to a base class, how can I access a property of the inherited class if I know that my reference is to the inherited class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'd like to do something like the following with my code:

```
BaseClass class;

if (BaseClass is InheritedClass)
{
    class.MethodOnlyInInheritedClass();
}
```

However I get an error that BaseClass does not contain a definition for MethodOnlyInInheritedClass. It doesn't, but I know based on the previous test that my particular reference to BaseClass is an inherited type that DOES contain that method. I tried casting class as InheritedClass but that didn't work.

Is there a way to do what I'm seeking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be compile time error **does not contain definition for...**

Define `MethodOnlyInInheritedClass` as a virtual method in your base class (or have it as an abstract method in abstract base class) and override same in `InheritedClass`

Comment: Oh right! Of course, guess I'm just tired. Thanks a ton!

Comment: yeah I was trying to but it told me I had to wait a few minutes, all done now